How to run trivy image scan inside Azure DevOps
I want to run trivy sbom generator for a number of images, pushed to Azure Container registry from Azure DevOps pipeline.
My task looks like
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MySubscription'
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az acr login --name ACR_Name
    
      docker run --rm -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory):/src aquasec/trivy image --format cyclonedx --output /src/sbom.json ACR_Name.azurecr.io/IMAGENAME:latest

Unfortunately, it does not work that way with the exception

2024-11-12T12:24:45Z  FATAL   Fatal error image scan error: scan error:
unable to initialize a scanner: unable to initialize an image scanner:
unable to find the specified image
"ACR_NAME/IMAGENAME:latest" in ["docker"
"containerd" "podman" "remote"]: 4 errors occurred:

docker error:
unable to inspect the image
(...): Cannot connect
to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker
daemon running?
containerd error: containerd socket not found:
/run/containerd/containerd.sock
podman error: unable to initialize
Podman client: no podman socket found: stat podman/podman.sock: no
such file or directory
remote error: GET
https://ACR_NAME/oauth2/token?scope=repository%3A...%3Apull&service=...:
UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required, visit
https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.


At the same time I can run docker pull IMAGENAME from inside this script as expected. I even tried to run it prior to running trivy, but it looks like it does not use local images (result is exactly the same)
Is it possible to "pass" authorization inside the container?

What was the behavior if you ran docker run --rm -v $(SomeLocalPath):/src aquasec/trivy image --format cyclonedx --output /src/sbom.json ACR_Name.azurecr.io/IMAGENAME:latest directly on that agent machine?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT sorry, not sure what do you suggest to test? Replace $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) with something else? Just in case the agent machine is one of "pool: vmImage: ubuntu-latest"

I wonder if you have tried that docker run command on a local Linux machine without running in pipelines. Was it working? It may help isolate the cause of the issue.

Yes, on a local machine it was working as expected

According to documentation here
You should create service principal with AcrPull permissions
export SP_DATA=$(az ad sp create-for-rbac --name TrivyTest --role AcrPull --scope "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/<registry_name>")

Then you need these credentials:
# must set TRIVY_USERNAME empty char
export AZURE_CLIENT_ID$(echo $SP_DATA | jq -r .appId)
export AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET$(echo $SP_DATA | jq -r .password)
export AZURE_TENANT_ID$(echo $SP_DATA | jq -r .tenant)

and you should be able to run it on this way:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MySubscription'
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az acr login --name ACR_Name
    
      docker run --rm -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory):/src \
         -e AZURE_CLIENT_ID=$AZURE_CLIENT_ID \
         -e AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=$AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET \
         -e AZURE_TENANT_ID=$AZURE_TENANT_ID \
         aquasec/trivy image --format cyclonedx --output /src/sbom.json ACR_Name.azurecr.io/IMAGENAME:latest
    env:
      AZURE_CLIENT_ID: $(AZURE_CLIENT_ID)
      AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: $(AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET)
      AZURE_TENANT_ID: $(AZURE_TENANT_ID)

I assumed you stored credentials in secrets in variable group which you linked to the pipeline.
And if you want to install trivy on the agent instead of using docker image you can check this tutorial.

To expand a bit on @Krzysztof Madej answer - you do not need to create a separate Service Principal if you already run it inside AzureCLI task with a service connection that can pull images from the private repository.
There is a addSpnToEnvironment option for this task that will expose connection details as environment variables, also there is no need to login to car using cli if you plan to use those images only for scanning:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MySubscription'
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    inlineScript: |
      docker run --rm -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory):/src \
         -e AZURE_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId \
         -e AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey \
         -e AZURE_TENANT_ID=$tenantId \
         aquasec/trivy image --format cyclone-dx --output /src/sbom.json ACR_Name.azurecr.io/IMAGENAME:latest

